# IKVM.Reflection for emitting IL at run time for Windows Store applications?

Tags: windows-runtime, reflection.emit, il, ikvm, assembly-loading

I saw a post on [IKVM.Reflection](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2012/07/enter-ikvm.html) by Marc Gravell, and here's what I found at IKVM [User's Guide](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=User%27s_Guide):

> There are two main ways of using IKVM.NET:
>
> - Dynamically: In this mode, Java classes and jars are used directly to execute Java applications on the .NET runtime. Java bytecode is translated on the fly into CIL and no further steps are necessary. The full Java class loader model is supported in this mode.
> - Statically: ...

I want to use it for emitting and executing IL inside WinRT applications. Are there any fundamental problems why this would be impossible to do? Like a policy from Microsoft, or technical restrictions preventing execution of (possibly patched) Reflection & IL Emitting code from IKVM?

If that's not possible, are there any options for loading assemblies at run time (assuming that I emit them on an external server and download from there to a local app folder)?

Comment: Interesting question. It does, however, first beg the question: can you get IKVM.Reflection to *compile* for that platform. I hadn't considered the options in terms of meta-programming, but it sounds an edge case in terms of validity.

Comment: @Marc: I'm going to try that, but so far I struggle with compiling it on normal .NET, because it depends on Visual Studio 2008 and I have only 2012.

Comment: you've confused me there; I've never seen 2012 struggle with a 2008 project, once the csproj is updated

Comment: OK, the answer is no. It won't compile for WinRT without significant changes. Probably I need to understand its design and implementation first, and maybe contact the author.

Comment: I was able to compile it for .NET 4.5 Client Profile, but on WinRT many types are missing.

Comment: tell me about it ;p (meaning: yes, I have observed that; painful, isn't it...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IKVM.NET's dynamic mode has nothing to do with IKVM.Reflection. IKVM.Reflection is only used by the static compiler.

While it is possible to compile IKVM.Reflection for the .NET core profile (with some tweaks), this doesn't get you any closer to dynamically generating code, unless you break out of the .NET core profile "sandbox" (which is possible, but I assume would violate the Window Store policies).